tls session channel binding substitute: the search for common material between java and csharp
Since java JSSE doesn't support channel binding tokens (CBT) yet, I can't write MitM-proof authentication handshakes over a delegated TLS connection using the simple "tls-unique" token that the RFC 5056 and mostly https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5929.html describes.
If you want to know why a CBT is critical in application level authentication, see https://csb.stevekerrison.com/post/2022-01-channel-binding/
The "tls-server-end-point" token is not available either, but it made me think that I could brew some substitute from the server's public key cert that both peer should agree on (if there is no MitM).
So I thought, ok, let's sha256 the expected/seen server's public key on each side and use that as a token.
My problem is that one side is in java, the other in c#, and they can't produce a common byte[] that would be comparable. I mean, the APIs do report various encoded format of the cert, or public key, or signature, but they are not the same format across those languages.
I managed to get a c# client connect to a java server, controlling both sources, and on each side drill into the RSA public key to find the modulus and exponent (and even then, the byte[] representation of a BigInteger was still slightly off by a sign byte), but I'd like to not have to be aware of all the cert types like that. Doing so won't survive long with the noise of all the future TLS changes. It would mean maintenance patches especially in 2 languages.
My questions are, what formats are these cert, public keys and signatures, how to parse them and why aren't the byte[] representing them exactly the same across implementations, since they were send over TCP/TLS protocol?
---- csharp client options: [hostname [port]]--------
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Net.Sockets;

class DumpCerts
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string server = args.Length>0 ? args[0] : "google.com";
        int port = args.Length>1 ? int.Parse(args[1]) : 443;
        
        using (var client = new TcpClient(server, port)) {
            using (var sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(CertificateValidationCallback), null))
            {
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(server);
                var remoteCertificate = sslStream.RemoteCertificate as X509Certificate2;

                if (remoteCertificate != null)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("Certificate: " + Convert.ToBase64String(remoteCertificate.RawData));
                    //Console.WriteLine("Public Key: " + Convert.ToBase64String(remoteCertificate.GetPublicKey()));
                    
                    X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
                    chain.Build(remoteCertificate);
                    int i=0;
                    foreach (var element in chain.ChainElements)
                    {
                        var cert = element.Certificate as X509Certificate2;
                        var pubk = cert.PublicKey;
                        //NOTE: cert.GetPublicKey() is a byte[] equals to pubk.EncodedKeyValue.RawData
                        
                        byte[] sig = cert.GetRawCertData();
                        
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\n-----------\npub key["+i+"]: "+cert.Subject
                            +"\npubl key : " + pubk
                            +"\npubl key oid: " + pubk.Oid
                            +"\npubl key oid value: " + pubk.Oid.Value
                            +"\npubk.enc key val  len: " + (pubk.EncodedKeyValue.RawData).Length
                            +"\npubk.enc key val  hex: " + byteArrayToHex(pubk.EncodedKeyValue.RawData)
                            +"\nsig len: " + sig.Length
                            +"\nsig hex: " + byteArrayToHex(sig)
                        );
                        
                        //using (var rsa = RSA.Create()) {
                        //  rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(pubk.EncodedKeyValue.RawData, out _);
                        //  byte[] publicKeyBytes = rsa.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo();
                        using (RSA rsa = remoteCertificate.GetRSAPublicKey())
                        {
                            var rsaParameters = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
                            Console.WriteLine("\n"
                            +"\nmodulus  len: "+ (rsaParameters.Modulus.Length)
                            +"\nmodulus  hex: "+ byteArrayToHex(rsaParameters.Modulus)
                            
                            +"\nexponent len: "+ (rsaParameters.Exponent.Length)
                            +"\nexponent hex: "+ byteArrayToHex(rsaParameters.Exponent)
                            );
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static bool CertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true; // Always accept the certificate
    }
    
    static string byteArrayToHex(byte[] input) {
        int bytesPerLine = 64;
        char[] HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF".ToCharArray();
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesPerLine];
        int offset = 0;

        while (offset < input.Length) {
            int length = Math.Min(buffer.Length, input.Length - offset);
            Array.Copy(input, offset, buffer, 0, length);
            
            StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder ascii = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                int v = buffer[i] & 0xFF;
                hex.Append(HEX[v >> 4]);
                hex.Append(HEX[v & 0x0F]);
                ascii.Append((v >= 32 && v <= 127) ? (char)buffer[i] : '.');
            }
            result.AppendFormat("\n\t{0,-" + (2 * bytesPerLine) + "} | {1}", hex.ToString(), ascii.ToString());
            offset += length;
        }
        
        return result.ToString();
    }
    
}

------ java server options:
-i <bindip>
-ks <server.jks>  <storepass>  <keypass>
package clientserverkit;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateEncodingException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.net.ssl.ExtendedSSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SNIServerName;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSessionContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

public class DumpCerts {
    private boolean verbose = false;
    
    private String bindIp;
    private int port = 33300;
    
    private String cafilename;
    private char[] capwd;
    
    private String ksfilename;
    private char[] kspwd;
    private char[] keypwd;

    //---
    
    private SSLContext ctx;
    private InetAddress bindAddr;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DumpCerts dc = new DumpCerts();
        dc.parseOptions(args);
        dc.initTls();
        dc.doServer();
    }
    
    void parseOptions(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        for(int i=0; i<args.length; ) {
            String opt = args[i++];
            switch(opt) {
                case "-v": verbose = true; break;
                case "-i": bindIp = args[i++]; break;
                case "-p": port = Integer.parseInt(args[i++]); break;
                case "-ca": cafilename = args[i++]; capwd = args[i++].toCharArray(); break;
                case "-ks": ksfilename = args[i++]; kspwd = args[i++].toCharArray(); keypwd = args[i++].toCharArray(); break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown option "+opt);
            }
        }
        
        if(bindIp!=null) {
            bindAddr = bindIp!=null && !bindIp.equalsIgnoreCase("-") ? InetAddress.getByName(bindIp) : null;
        }
    }
    
    private void initTls() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException {
        KeyManager[] kma =null;
        TrustManager[] tma = null;
        
        //--- setup key
        
        Provider bcProvider = SSLContext.getDefault().getProvider();
        
        if(ksfilename!=null) {
            File ksfile = new File(ksfilename);
            if(!ksfile.isFile() && ksfile.canRead())
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot read "+ksfile);
            
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm(), bcProvider);
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(ksfile, kspwd);
            kmf.init(ks, kspwd);
            Arrays.fill(kspwd, 's');
            Arrays.fill(keypwd, 'k');
            kma = kmf.getKeyManagers();
        }
        
        
        //--- setup trusted CA
        
        if(cafilename!=null) {
            File cafile = new File(cafilename);
            if(!cafile.isFile() && cafile.canRead()){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot read "+cafile);
            }
            
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm(), bcProvider);
            KeyStore caks = KeyStore.getInstance(cafile, capwd);
            Arrays.fill(capwd, 'c');
            tmf.init(caks);
            tma = tmf.getTrustManagers();
        }   
        
        //--- make tls ctx and pull socket factories
        
        SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
        ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS", bcProvider);
        //ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        ctx.init(kma, tma, sr);
    }
    
    void doServer() throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            SSLServerSocketFactory sssf = ctx.getServerSocketFactory();
            SSLServerSocket sss = (SSLServerSocket)sssf.createServerSocket(port, 50, bindAddr);
            //sss.setNeedClientAuth(true);//mandatory
            sss.setWantClientAuth(true);//optional
            serverSocket = sss;
            while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
                try(Socket s = serverSocket.accept()) {
                    dumpInfo(s, verbose);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if(serverSocket!=null)
                serverSocket.close();
        }
    }
    
    static void dumpInfo(Socket s, boolean verbose) {
        System.out.println("\n\n===== socket dump ===================================================================================");
        System.out.println("local skt : "+s.getLocalSocketAddress());
        System.out.println("remote skt : "+s.getRemoteSocketAddress());
        if(s instanceof SSLSocket ss) {
            SSLSession sess = ss.getSession();
            System.out.println("sess proto    : "+sess.getProtocol());
            System.out.println("sess cipher suite: "+sess.getCipherSuite());
            System.out.println("sess id: (hex) "+bytesToHex(sess.getId()));
            System.out.println("sess peer host: "+sess.getPeerHost());
            System.out.println("sess peer port: "+sess.getPeerPort());
            
            System.out.println("sess local principal  : "+sess.getLocalPrincipal());
            dumpCerts("local", sess.getLocalCertificates(), verbose);
            
            try {
                System.out.println("sess peer principal: "+sess.getPeerPrincipal());
                dumpCerts("peer", sess.getPeerCertificates(), verbose);
            } catch (SSLPeerUnverifiedException e) {
                System.out.println("(peer unverified)");
            }
            
            for(String n: sess.getValueNames()) {
                System.out.println("sess value["=="]: "+sess.getValue(n));
            }
            System.out.println("sess creation time: "+new Date(sess.getCreationTime()));
            System.out.println("sess access time  : "+new Date(sess.getLastAccessedTime()));
            System.out.println("sess pkt buff : "+sess.getPacketBufferSize());
            System.out.println("sess app buff : "+sess.getApplicationBufferSize());
            
            SSLSessionContext ctx = sess.getSessionContext();
            if(ctx!=null) {
                System.out.println("sess ctx sess cache sz: "+ctx.getSessionCacheSize());
                System.out.println("sess ctx sess timeout : "+ctx.getSessionTimeout());
            }
            
            if(sess instanceof ExtendedSSLSession xsession) {
                List<SNIServerName> list = xsession.getRequestedServerNames();
                if(list!=null)
                    list.forEach(sni -> System.out.println("xsess sni: "+sni.toString()));
                System.out.println("xsess local supported algos: "+Arrays.asList(xsession.getLocalSupportedSignatureAlgorithms()));
                System.out.println("xsess peer  supported algos: "+Arrays.asList(xsession.getPeerSupportedSignatureAlgorithms()));
            }
        }
    }

    
    static void dumpCerts(String prefix, Certificate[] certs, boolean verbose) {
        if(certs==null) {
            System.out.println("(no "+prefix+" certs)");
            return;
        }
        
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            for(int i=0; i<certs.length; i++) {
                md.reset();
                PublicKey publicKey = certs[i].getPublicKey();
                byte[] pubk = publicKey.getEncoded();
                byte[] sha256 = md.digest(pubk);
                System.out.println("\n-----certs["+i+"]------------");
                System.out.println(prefix+" certs["+i+"] publ key algo="+publicKey.getAlgorithm()+", format="+publicKey.getFormat());
                System.out.println(prefix+" certs["+i+"] publ key enc len : "+pubk.length);
                System.out.println(prefix+" certs["+i+"] publ key enc hex : "+bytesToHex(pubk));
                System.out.println(prefix+" certs["+i+"] sha256(publ key enc) : "+bytesToHex(sha256));
                
                if(certs[i] instanceof X509Certificate xcert) {
                    try {
                        byte[] tbsder = xcert.getTBSCertificate();
                        System.out.println(prefix+" certs["+i+"] tbsder len : "+tbsder.length);
                        System.out.println(prefix+" certs["+i+"] tbsder hex : "+bytesToHex(tbsder));
                    } catch (CertificateEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    byte[] sig = xcert.getSignature();
                    System.out.println(prefix+" certs["+i+"] sig len : "+sig.length);
                    System.out.println(prefix+" certs["+i+"] sig hex : "+bytesToHex(sig));
                }
                
                if(publicKey instanceof RSAPublicKey rsapk) {
                    System.out.println(prefix+" certs["+i+"] len(modulus) : "+rsapk.getModulus().toByteArray().length);
                    System.out.println(prefix+" certs["+i+"] hex(modulus) : "+bytesToHex(rsapk.getModulus().toByteArray()));
                    
                    System.out.println(prefix+" certs["+i+"] len(exponent): "+rsapk.getPublicExponent().toByteArray().length);
                    System.out.println(prefix+" certs["+i+"] hex(exponent): "+bytesToHex(rsapk.getPublicExponent().toByteArray()));
                }
            }
            if(verbose) {
                for(int i=0; i<certs.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("\n-----"+prefix+" certs["+i+"].toString()---------\n"+certs[i]);
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            System.out.println("(hash algo not found): "+e);
        }
        
    }
    
    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] input) {
        int bytesPerLine = 64;
        char[] HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
        
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesPerLine];
        int offset = 0;
        
        while (offset < input.length) {
            int length = Math.min(buffer.length, input.length - offset);
            System.arraycopy(input, offset, buffer, 0, length);
            
            StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder ascii = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                int v = buffer[i] & 0xFF;
                hex.append(HEX[v >>> 4]);
                hex.append(HEX[v & 0x0F]);
                ascii.append((v >= 32 && v <= 127) ? (char)buffer[i] : '.');
            }
            
            //result.append("\n\t").append(hex).append(" | ").append(ascii);
            result.append(String.format("\n\t%-"+(2*bytesPerLine)+"s | %s", hex.toString(), ascii.toString()));
            offset += length;
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
    
}


Found it.
Csharp needed to pull
byte[] certder = cert.GetRawCertData();

while java needed to pull
byte[] certder = certs[i].getEncoded();

